# Trying to hide div but it's not working

Tags: jquery

I have an email for that is supposed to disappear when email and name are entered and sent.

Based on some examples I have found I think i have whatt makes sense in my script... but it's not working and no debug errors either...

Just to be clear it sends the name and email, it just doesn't disappear.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: "email_form.php",
        data:{
          name: $('input[name="name"]').val(),
          email: $('input[name="email"]').val()
        },
        success: 
          $("#form").hide()
      });                 
    });
  });
</script>
```

and here's the HTML

```
<div class="col-md-4">
          <form name="htmlform" method="post" id="form">
            <input class="blacked left form text-left" type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" required>
            <input class="blacked left form text-left" type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" required>
            <input class="blacked left form text-left" id="submit" type="button" name="submit" value="send">
          </form>
        </div>
```

and just in case neither of those show you enough info, here's the [Site Link](http://thecoxband.com/index1.html)

Comment: It is working for me. Clear your browser cache and try again.

Comment: Works for me... Check your network tab in the developer console when you hit send and see what happens when it tries to `post` to that php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
success: function() {
      $("#form").hide();
      /* other code here */
}
```

in order to trigger the desired function actions on a success **callback**

Comment: Is this a change that could make his code work for him even though it already works for us?

Comment: @Jason The original code hides the form when the AJAX is sent, not when the response is received.